# Package sun.font not visible in java 11 while upgrading it from java 8

Tags: java-8, upgrade, java-11

After moving from Java8 to Java11, I'm getting the error "package sun.font is not visible
(package sun.font is declared in module java.desktop, which does not export it)"

Comment: Yes, this is expected. Why do you need to access something in the `sun.font` package anyway?

Comment: From [Why Developers Should Not Write Programs That Call 'sun' Packages](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/faq-sun-packages.html): **The sun.* packages are not part of the supported, public interface.** And that note is decades old.